# mssql-jdbc-6.3.4.jre8-preview.jar does not have sqljdbc_auth.dll

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am using JDBC in my code and I get this error:

```
Sep 24, 2019 9:01:47 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI <clinit>
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path
```

I understand to fix this, the path of `sqljdbc_auth.dll` must be given in java library path.

But when I extracted my JDBC jar (`mssql-jdbc-6.3.4.jre8-preview.jar`), I could not find `sqljdbc_auth.dll` at all inside it.

What do I do now? Pls help!

Comment: I think you only the DLLs if you download the driver from the Microsoft site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#available-downloads-of-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

As [documented](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc#download-the-dlls) on the project page of the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver, https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc, you need to manually download them:

> ## Download the DLLs
>
> For some features (e.g. Integrated Authentication and Distributed
> Transactions), you may need to use the `sqljdbc_xa` and `sqljdbc_auth`
> DLLs. They can be downloaded from the [Microsoft Download Center](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=868287)

That link actually points to an installer (self-extracting zip) of the JDBC driver. This installer contains the DLLs. If you're using a different version, you may need to find the installer of that version in the Microsoft Download Center.